# LUIS.ai Is there anyway to restore a deleted intent, or just undo all changes?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Is there anyone to undo changes on a LUIS model? I accidentally deleted an intent. I have not trained the model for the changes. Is there any way to undo this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such possibility. You need to frequently export your application so that you can restore it, or work with versions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we **cannot recover the deleted intent**.